# Create a vector of dates in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have three columns in my data:

```
mall_id product_id sold_date
 13       10001     04-01-2020
 13       10002     05-06-2020
 14       10001     03-01-2020
 13       10001     05-02-2020
```

I want to create a vector from sold_date for each of the mall_id, product_id unique combination.
Vector should be such that length of the vector should be max(sold_date) - min(sold_date) and it should be in the form of 1s and 0s (E.g. [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]) such that each digit represents whether a purchase was made or not that day for the mall_id product_id combo. (i.e. 0 means no purchase for that day and 1 means a purchase was made].

After creating the vectors, I want to transform it as a new column in pandas with following numpy functions:

```
times_1 = np.diff(np.where(vector))
np.std(times_1)/np.mean(times_1)
```

I am able to apply the numpy functions for a single vector but unable to create the vectors in my dataframe and then apply them for every value in the column. I tried several ways to do it but couldn't figure it out as I am new to pandas.

Can someone provide some direction? I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

My Pandas skills are a bit rusty, so my attempt might be suboptimal.

Used modules:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Setting up the DataFrame (you already have it):

```
columns = ['mall_id', 'product_id', 'sold_date']
data = [[13, 10001, '04-01-2020'],
        [13, 10002, '05-06-2020'],
        [14, 10001, '03-01-2020'],
        [14, 10001, '05-02-2020'],
        [13, 10001, '05-02-2020']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Converting column sold_date into proper dates (I don't know if the first or second part of the dates represents the month/day, so this might be wrong):

```
df['sold_date'] = [dt.date(int(date[6:]), int(date[3:5]), int(date[:2]))
                   for date in df['sold_date'].values]
```

Setting up an array with the covered range of days (this is done globally, i.e. not for each mall_id and product_id combination):

```
start, end = df['sold_date'].min(), df['sold_date'].max()
days = np.array([start + dt.timedelta(days=i)
                 for i in range((end - start).days + 1)])
```

Changing the index into a multi-index from columns mall_id and product_id:

```
df.set_index(['mall_id', 'product_id'], drop=True, inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Looping over the mall_id and product_id combinations, creating the corresponding vector, and storing it in a dictionary:

```
# Initialising dictionary for results
sales = {m_id: {} for m_id, _ in df.index}
# Loop over index
for m_id, p_id in df.index:
    # Determining on which days sales happened
    sale_days = np.array([(1 if day in df.loc[(m_id, p_id)].values else 0)
                          for day in days])
    # Storing result in dictionary
    sales[m_id][p_id] = sale_days
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def trans_dt(x):
    m, M = x.min(), x.max()
    r = [1 if x.eq(m+pd.to_timedelta(d, unit="D")).any() else 0 for d in range((M-m).days+1)]
    return r

# only if not done already:
df["sold_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["sold_date"], format="%d-%m-%Y")

res = df.groupby(["mall_id", "product_id"], as_index=False)["sold_date"].agg(trans_dt)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> res

   mall_id  ...                                          sold_date
0       13  ...  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
1       13  ...                                                [1]
2       14  ...  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```